# How do I customize keyboard shortcuts in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Some Windows shortcut key combinations are interfering with my WinSplit Revolution shortcuts. 
Where are these shortcuts defined in XP and how can I change them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing some via HotKeyBind, AutoIt, AutoHotkey and such programs. You cannot change most of the system implemented default ones (like <kbd>Win</kbd>+  <kbd>E</kbd> for explorer, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> ... and such). I had a question regarding this on SO, and this has been one of the Windows annoyances for me for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

If the conflicts are ones that start programs, then they are defined as shortcuts in .lnk properties - however there are no defaults so you -- or someone -- has to have set them.

You can go into explorer and do a properties on each .lnk file -- or if you have some programming skills you can do as I did -- see bottom of this answer.

I found this was implemented "horribly" in XP -- apparently the start menu "tree" of .lnk files is NOT scanned and loaded into a little table.   So if you haven't used a shortcut in a while it will have to look thru and open every .lnk file until it finds the right one.

Instead I prefer Macro Express, and while fee-based, is definitely worthwhile.

I wrote my own "find all shortcuts" program, which is in KEDIT and thus not "portable" (for it relies on non-free Kedit to run).  But the LOGIC might help someone else do a search:

The logic is this:  read the 65th and 66th byte of every .lnk file in the documents and settings\ files.

The 65th byte is the "key" with a decimal 220 meaning "\"; and the 66th byte is a bit of "what other keys go with it":

'00000110' = "Ctrl+ Alt "
'00000101' = "Shift+Alt "
'00000011' = "Shift+Ctrl"
'00000100' = "Alt       "
'00000010' = "Ctrl      "
'00000001' = "Shift     "

P.S. I probably could rewrite this in AUTO-IT to be portable if there is a need and no substitute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where they are defined or how to change them (I don't you really can change most, if you can at all), but here is a [list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301583) of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try [HotKeyBind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hotkeybind/files/). You find a short description [here](http://www.techmalaya.com/2008/05/23/windows-shortcut-keys-hotkeybind/).